# Messed up diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

hi I'd like to draw following diagram with TikZ-feynman pakage but output is so messed up. what can i do?

[image]

```
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=i1 to f1]{
i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
a -- [photon] b,
f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a){\(\alpha,\mu\)};
    \vertex [right=of a] (b){\(\beta,\nu\)};
    \vertex [above right=of b] (f1) ;
    \vertex [below right=of b] (f2);
    \diagram* {
        i1 -- [fermion, momentum'=\(P_1\)] a -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(P_2\)] i2,
        a -- [gluon] b,
        f1 -- [fermion, momentum'=\(P_3\)] b -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(P_4\)] f2,
    };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output of this code is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably got a warning: "Package tikz-feynman Warning: LuaTeX is required if you wish to have vertices automatically placed." Compiling with LuaLaTeX should get at least the first diagram right. For the second, try `\diagram` instead of `\diagram*`.

Comment: my main language is persian so I need compile it with xelatex. can you offer me another solution?

Comment: @hosseinmohseni You can externalize the picture and using the `lualatex` engine then for it, this needs some work in the preamble, though. Given the proper fonts, Persian should be doable in LuaLaTeX, too. – Or you place the nodes manually …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! First of all, the `tikz-feynman` package heavily relies on mechanisms for which LuaLaTeX is needed. Therefore, you might want to compile your code with LuaLaTeX. Thanks to these mechanisms, placement of the vertices can be done mostly automatically. If you cannot use LuaLaTeX, however, you need to revert to manual placement of the vertices.

The following code uses such manual placement. It should work with PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX as well, although a lot of warnings will probably be issued (and I am not sure whether the output is what you intend it to be):

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=1.5cm of a] (b);
    \vertex [above left=of a] (i1);
    \vertex [below left=of a] (i2);
    \vertex [above right=of b] (f1);
    \vertex [below right=of b] (f2);
    \diagram* {
        (i1) -- [fermion] (a) -- [fermion] (i2),
        (a) -- [photon] (b),
        (f1) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (f2),
    };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a){\(\alpha,\mu\)};
    \vertex [right=1.5cm of a] (b){\(\beta,\nu\)};
    \vertex [above left=of a] (i1);
    \vertex [below left=of a] (i2);
    \vertex [above right=of b] (f1);
    \vertex [below right=of b] (f2);
    \diagram* {
        (i1) -- [fermion, momentum=\(P_1\)] (a) -- [anti fermion, momentum=\(P_2\)] (i2),
        (a) -- [gluon] (b),
        (f1) -- [fermion, momentum'=\(P_3\)] (b) -- [anti fermion, momentum'=\(P_4\)] (f2),
    };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works. thanks a lot

Comment: @hosseinmohseni But is the output even right? I am unfamiliar with such diagrams ...

Comment: it has a problem were vertex sign located but it can be solve(i think)